# avoiding slow motion when using css keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to achieve this button animation on hover using only CSS solution :

[image]

I've succeed on find a way doing this with css keyframe , but now i'm facing some an unexpected slow motion effect, for now I'm only experimenting this with the top left corner here is what I've done so far :

HTML

```
<a href=""><div class="borderTop"></div></a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20%;
    display: block;    
}

a:hover .borderTop {
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  -webkit-animation: topTheleft  2s alternate;
  animation: topTheleft  2s alternate;
}

.borderTop {
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    left: 50px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    50% { left: -30px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none; }
}
@-o-keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    50% { left: -30px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none;  }
}
@-moz-keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    50% { left: -30px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none;  }
}
@keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    50% { left: -30px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none;  }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fqk9j5gx/)**

any help on how to avoid this slow motion on the middle of the animation would be highly appreciated , thank you in advance

edit, is there a way to make the line hide when reach the `left: -70px` with a transition effect not ansta-hide, any other solution to do it are welcome too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the 50% lines:

```
@-webkit-keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none; }
}
@-o-keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none;  }
}
@-moz-keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none;  }
}
@keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none;  }
}
```

Comment: thank you this solved the fist problem :)  is there a way to make the line hide when reach the left: -70px with a transition effect not ansta-hide ?

Comment: I think the best you could do is to put 50% { left: -70px; } in your keyframes. So you have two animations: moves from A to B, stops and disappears a bit later.

Comment: merci c'est gentil :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the default timing function is ease-in-out : from one animation step to the other, the speed goes slow-fast-slow, to make it look more natural (real physics cannot make an object got from speed 0 to 100 instantaneously).

So what happens is the animation starts slow at 0%, goes fast, then slows down for the 50% step, then accelerates again

Is this what you are looking for ?
https://jsfiddle.net/kvyqyg19/1/

```
a:hover .borderTop {
  /* .. */ 
  -webkit-animation: topTheleft  2s alternate;
  animation: topTheleft  2s alternate;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes topTheleft {
    0% { left: -2px; }
    100% { left: -70px; display: none; }
}
/* .. */
```

I removed the middle (50%) step and set the **animation-timing-function: linear;**